# Apache, PHP, Centos 6

Tags: php, apache, http, virtualhost

When I navigate to my website (e.g. www.mydomain.com), the browser opens a pop-up window to download a file.

In my httpdocs folder i have:
- index.html
- index.php ()
- I do NOT have .htaccess file

Checking in the browser:
- www.mydomain.com/index.html -> it works fine
- www.mydomain.com/index.php  -> it works WRONG (it downloads the index.php file)
- www.mydomain.com            -> it works WRONG (it download "descarga" file with index.php contents).

PHP is installed, and when I run the `php -v` command, it says that I am using PHP 5.3

I have other domains on the same server working fine with php files, so AddHandler or LoadModule should not be the problem as far as PHP is a constant for all my domains.

This is my php.conf and looks like everythin is right:

```
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

What should I try to navigate to my domain successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the PHP module loaded. Somewhere in your config you should see something like:

```
LoadModule php5_module    modules/libphp5.so
```

Then, make you you add a handler to handle files with the `php` extension:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: I have rewritten my question with some more details:
- I have other domains on the same server working fine with php
- I have AddHandler and LoadModule properly configurated as far as the other domains are working.
So, it seems like this should not be the solution.
(Anyway, thanks for trying)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take advantage of `yum` as it can help you get things setup quickly, and allows for easy ways to update your server down the road per the `yum update` command. The following are some commands that may be of use to you:

```
yum update
yum install php*
yum install httpd*
yum update
chkconfig httpd on
/etc/init.d/httpd start
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not that easy as far as I need specific PHP versions and so on.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote, as the specific version wasn't requested in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

There was just one domain asking me to download a file, rest of domains were working fine.

I could not find what was the problem so I went to my Plesk Panel, I deleted that domain, and I created the same domain again. After that it was working fine.

My server is a Linux CentOS 6, and I use Parallel Plesk Panel 11.

Thanks to everybody that was trying to help me on this issue.

J. Pablo.